# why am i getting zero while i have initialized my instance variables?

Tags: java, class, variables, constructor

i have a simple java program below. i have declared instance integer variable "x1" and "x2", initialize them from parameters in my class constructor.
i have also declared an integer variable "diff" that works out the difference between "x1" and "x2" but the variable returns zero!! i don't know where the problem is and my constructor parameters are not zero!!!. i will appreciate any help

```
public class Smallest {
int x1;
int x2; 

public Smallest(int a,int b){
 this.x1=a;
 this.x2=b;
}

int diff = x2 - x1;   
public void draw(){
    System.out.println("X1= "+ x1 +"\n X2= "+ x2 +"\n diff= " +diff);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Smallest small=new Smallest(10,20);
small.draw();
}
}
```

here's the output

```
 X1= 10;
 X2= 20;
 diff= 0;
```

Comment: Because `diff` gets initialized _before_ calling the constructor with the result of `x2 - x1`, which is `0`.

Comment: so you mean instance variables are intitialized to their default if they are not initialized during creation? i mean, are they executed before the constructor? i thought java compiler will follow the default sequence execution?

Comment: Yes, they are initialized *before* the constructor gets called.

Comment: its really tricky. and to make matter worse, its not a syntax error or compile-time error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int diff = x2 - x1;` should be inside the `constructor` or inside the method `draw()` (depending on what you want to do with it).

**Remember:** By default int variables are initialized to 0. **Before** you call the constructor:

```
x1=0; 
x2=0; 
diff=x1-x2
    =0-0
    =0
```

When you call the constructor you give different values to `x1` and `x2` but you don't calculate the `diff` on the newly updated values.

After you call the constructor:

```
x1=10;
x2=20;
diff=0; // you don't recalculate it, it's not in the constructor or in the draw method.
```

Comment: but i have already initialized my x1 and x2? please explain to me clearly whats happening for me to get zero!

Comment: @gikarasojo kinene when you call the constructor, you intialize only x1 and x2. You never set diff to be x1-x2 after you have initialized them. To do this you have to choices: Calculate the diff in the constructor (in this case the diff variable must be an instance variable like x1 and x2) or calculate the diff inside the method draw() that you call.

Comment: @gikarasojo kinene see if it's clear now, I updated the answer.

Comment: so that means any operation on instance variables should be done inside methods or constuctors? what if i had initialize x1 and x2 directly during their declarion without passing through the constructor and call diff at the main method, will i still get a zero?

Comment: No. If you had intialized them since the beginning to 10 and 20 you would see diff=10

Comment: everything crystal clear. very tricky situation. but i understand now. thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is because diff is not inside any method it set during compile time. You should move it to the constructor or any other method to get correct value.

Example :

```
int diff;
public Smallest(int a,int b){
   this.x1=a;
   this.x2=b;
   this.diff=x2 - x1;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Member variables are initialized *before* your constructor is called. Thus diff is equal to 0 - 0 since x1 and x2 have not been set yet.

Comment: i thought java compiler will follow sequence execution, just the way i have arranged my codes? that is, it will initialize x1 and x2 before doing substraction